# Accessing the Magento REST API in Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-ee

We are working on multi technologies application, where user authentication will be handeled by LDAP, UI will be handled by Liferay.

Magento will keep track of orders and product catalogues and communicate via REST APIs.

Anybody please advise how to avoid the need of request token and access tokens.

Application should be able to authenticate using the consumer secret and consumer key generated while registering the application. 
Basically I want authentication should happen in backend, user should not be asked to key in the user credentials/ authorize to get access tokens as magento will not have any user authentication details

Many thanks in advance